# Memsql::Streamliner Python Transform

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, singlestore

I am working in the Memsql::Streamliner::Transform (Python) utility.  There is a transform method that must be overwritten to provide custom transform functionality.

`def transform(self, sql_context, dataframe, logger):`

`dataframe.column[0]` is a byte array (JSON string).

How do I convert the byte array into a DataFrame with named columns?

Goal:  Access individual columns within converted DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the underlying rdd with `dataframe.rdd` and map over it to transform each byte string into a list containing your columns. you can turn the resulting rdd back into a dataframe with named columns by providing the column list as the second argument to `createDataframe`.

Something like the following should work:

```
def parse(row):
   bytestring = row[0]
   json_data = convert_bytes_and_parse_json(bytestring)
   return [ json_data["mycolumn1"], json_data["mycolumn2"] ]

parsedRDD = dataframe.rdd.map(parse)
parsedDf = sql_context.createDataframe(parsedRDD, ["mycolumn1", "mycolumn2"])

# now you can access columns by name
parsedDf.select(parsedDf["mycolumn1"])
```

Comment: Your example helped.  Thanks.  However, it appears the columns are floating around in order.  If I access parsedDf[0], parsedDF[1], etc. every time I run the code different columns appear in the [0] spot, etc.  Thoughts?

Comment: are you returning a list in your `parse` function or are you returning a dict? i haven't tested this, but key ordering in a dict is not preserved so it may be choosing the order of the columns based on the first dict in your rdd.


in any case, you can access your columns directly with `df["colname"]` which is running `df.select("colname")` under the hood.